# Can't use RemoteWebDriver(Ghost,Phantom) via Selenium Grid2

Tags: phantomjs, selenium-grid, ghostdriver

I tried GhostDriver and Phantomjs today.
When I use GhostDriver, it works well.
start like this

> phantomjs  --webdriver=8910
>   then

```
new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:8910"), sCaps);
```

My selenium test case can pass.

Then I tried to use Selenium2Grid,
so I start selenium standalone server as a hub:

```
D:\_Try\selenium>java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.31.0.jar -role hub
2013-3-20 14:13:49 org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncher main
信息: Launching a selenium grid server
2013-03-20 14:13:50.026:INFO:osjs.Server:jetty-7.x.y-SNAPSHOT
2013-03-20 14:13:50.060:INFO:osjsh.ContextHandler:started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/,null}
2013-03-20 14:13:50.068:INFO:osjs.AbstractConnector:Started SocketConnector@0.0.0.0:4444
```

then register GhostDriver to the hub

```
C:\Users\administrator>phantomjs  --webdriver=8910 --webdriver-selenium-grid-hub=http://localhost:4444
PhantomJS is launching GhostDriver...
Ghost Driver running on port 8910
Registered with grid hub: http://localhost:4444/ (ok)
```

then I checked the registration via the Grid console: `http://localhost:4444/grid/console` and found phantomjs has already registered.
so I modified the code, the client should visit the grid:

```
new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444"), sCaps);
```

re-run the selenium test case,
I thought it would work well, but exception throws:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Map
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:218)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:111)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:129)
    at net.pipitest.selenium.trial.ghost.BaseTest.prepareDriver(BaseTest.java:117)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
```

I debugged into the code,
found that in RemoteWebDriver.class, the response is the source code of Selenium Grid Page (`http://localhost:4444`)
which should be a MAP Object like this(the below is what I get When using GhostDriver directly):
[platform=windows-7-32bit, acceptSslCerts=false, javascriptEnabled=true, browserName=phantomjs, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=false, version=phantomjs-1.8.1+ghostdriver-1.0.2, databaseEnabled=false, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, handlesAlerts=false, browserConnectionEnabled=false, webStorageEnabled=false, proxy={proxyType=direct}, nativeEvents=true, applicationCacheEnabled=false, takesScreenshot=false]

Does anyone meet this problem before?
Or any suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

1. `java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.31.0.jar -role hub` - run selenium grid hub
2. `phantomjs  --webdriver=8080 --webdriver-selenium-grid-hub=http ://localhost:4444` - run webdriver on port 8080 and integration with selenium grid
3. `new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://{lh or remote ip}:8080"), dCap);` run PhanomJSDriver in dCap must be phantomjs capability

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem, and the solution was simply to use 
    `URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub")`
instead of 
    `URL("http://localhost:4444/")`